# Choosing between "who have" or "with"

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction

Which of the following sentences is correct (if any)?:

> 1) a man with a green card can enter.
>
> 2) men with green card can enter.
>
> 3) men with green cards can enter.
>
> 4) All men who have a green card can enter.

Comment: On what basis should we judge?  Grammar, capitalization or both?

Comment: is there any grammar errors? which is more frequent? weird?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) a man with a green card can enter.

Correct, but the initial "A" should be capitalized because it begins a sentence.
 ie. "A man with a green card can enter."

> 2) men with green card can enter.

Incorrect--men is plural, you have more than one man.  Each man has his own green card, so the green cards must also be plural.  Also "men" needs to be capitalized as it begins a sentence.  So the correct thing to say would be "Men with green *cards* can enter."

> 3) men with green cards can enter.

Aha, so here your example number 3 is exactly how I corrected example 2.  Though again "men" should be capitalized, as it begins a sentence.

> 4) All men who have a green card can enter.

Correct.  You could also say "All men who have green cards can enter" (or even "All men with green cards can enter").

To get to the root of your question--"with" and "who have" are both correct in these sentences, and are interchangeable.  Some of your sentences had other grammatical issues, but "who have" and "with" were always correct.

Comment: #2 could also become "Men with a green card can enter."

Answer (score 0):

As usual, **context is everything**. All phrases seem to be grammatically correct. Let me show you the respective contexts:

> 1) a man with a green card can enter.

You have given different color cards to different people. You are certain there is only one green card, so there's only a single person who has a green one.

> 2) men with green card can enter.

Correction, "men with *a* green card can enter". Your "cards" are big and heavy. Several people may hold each card. You are letting those who carry a green one (the same green one) to enter.

> 3) men with green cards can enter.
>   4) All men who have a green card can enter.

There are several green cards (and several non-green ones). Both correct, as in WendiKidd's answer.

Comment: in fact the green cards are small. some people have one or more green cards and some other don't have green cards. Now a placard is attached above a door which say men with a green card can enter. or a boss says to someone : "don't let all in. only men with a green card can enter."